# Python Query SELECT WHERE is not working. Two alternatives and I cannot get it

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm stuck with a Query I cannot go ahead.
I'm trying to do a query , but I get some errors.

When I do this:

```
def achaGrp(grp): {grp = 'SUPORTE', e.g}
    bclogon=con.cursor()
    ...
    sql='SELECT id_group,gp FROM ugroup u WHERE u.gp = %s'
        bclogon.execute(sql,grp)
        registro = bclogon.fetchone()
```

I get `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

If I do this:

```
def achaGrp(grp): {grp = 'SUPORTE', e.g}
    bclogon=con.cursor()
    ...
    sql='SELECT id_group,gp FROM ugroup u WHERE u.gp = %s'
    bclogon.execute(sql,[grp])
    registro = bclogon.fetchone()
```

I get `can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str`

How can I do?

The query below gives me a right answer, since I use two values within a list [matricula,datahora]:

```
def achaReg(matricula,datahora):
    ...
    bclogon=con.cursor()
    sql='SELECT id, matricula, datahora '
        'FROM reg2023 u '
        'WHERE u.matricula = %s AND datahora = %s'
    bclogon.execute(sql,[matricula,datahora])
    registros = bclogon.fetchone()
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I edited my quesrtion above. `grp` is a parameter passed to a function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre], i.e. a single piece of python code that reproduces the error message. In the question, it is still unclear what `grp` is, and the error is likely related to it.

Comment: 1) Where is `bclogon` coming from? 2) Is `grp` a `str` a `dict` a `tuple` or something else?

Comment: Hi, @He3lixxx I reformatted my question.

Comment: This `bclogon.execute(sql,grp)` fails because `grp` is being seen as a `sequence` not a complete parameter and is being sequenced into more values then you have placeholders. You would need to do `bclogon.execute(sql, (grp, ))` to get one entire value to match `u.gp = %s`. Though your second example says that would probably fail with the same error, `(not "tuple") to str`.  To your code add `print(type(grp))` to see what you are actually passing in. I'm guessing it is a `tuple`.  Also read [Passing Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: Best bet is `grp` is something like `(val1, val2, ..., valN)`, `type(grp) = tuple`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, in fact it was a type issue. I get successful when I formatted `registro = str(bclogon.fetchone()[0])` after the second alternative: `bclogon.execute(sql,[grp])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me, thanks also to who gave a negative vote to my question ;-)

The error message is not referencing the action `bclogon.execute(sql,[grp])` but the following command: `registro = bclogon.fetchone()` because the result of `bclogon.execute...` is a tuple, not a str value. So I had to do so, to eliminate the error message:

```
sql='SELECT id_group,gp FROM ugroup u WHERE u.gp = %s'
bclogon.execute(sql,[grp])
registro = str(bclogon.fetchone()[0])
```